# Highlight a word in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to highlight a **word/letter** in a text by changing its color\colour using python 2.7?

try:
using clint.

```
>>> from clint.textui import puts, colored
>>> puts(colored.red('Text in Red'))
```

Text in Red
but i want to color only the 'x' in the 'Text' for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import termcolor

string = 'Text in Red'

string = string.replace('x', termcolor.colored('x', 'red'))

print string
```

Comment: Please make sure your answer is properly formatted using the formatting tools provided when writing an answer. Also, it is best to actually provide an explanation around what your code actually does to help readers understand.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work.

```
>>> from clint.textui import puts, colored
>>> puts('Te'+colored.red('x')+'t in Red')
```

---

Let me explain why this works by first explaining how colors are displayed in the console.

When you want to tell the console to change colors you would think you would have to do some special system call or something, but all you have to do is output some special characters called an ansi escape sequence. Clint handles this for you. When you used the clint.ansi.red function, the escape character for red was added before the x and the escape character to reset everything back to normal was added after the x.

This means that, `'Te'+colored.red('x')+'t in Red'` is the same thing as `'Te\x1b[31m\x1b[22mx\x1b[39m\x1b[22mt in Red'`, and you can continue to add text in others colors to your hearts content.

---

Also, clint handles this, but just for informational purposes, if you want to see the full list of color escape sequences they can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisopedia/8754917). There are other ansi codes that allow you to do things like changing the position of the cursor. You can find a list of all of the ansi codes [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes). If you mess with ansi codes outside of the clint library, make sure you're taking into account every flow of control including unexpected exceptions that need will need to revert the text back to normal. It's no fun to execute a program, run into some errors that turn the console red, and then have the program exit, but you're still left with a red console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-external library approach which I tend to use a lot

```
class bcolors:
    RED     = '\033[91m'
    GREEN   = '\033[92m'
    BLUE    = '\033[94m'
    CYAN    = '\033[96m'
    WHITE   = '\033[97m'
    YELLOW  = '\033[93m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[95m'
    GREY    = '\033[90m'
    BLACK   = '\033[90m'
    DEFAULT = '\033[99m'
    BOLD    = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    END     = '\033[0m'

print(bcolors.WHITE + foo + bcolors.END)
print(bcolors.GREEN + bar + bcolors.END)
```